# How to find string path in a matrix of characters?

Tags: matrix, language-agnostic

How would you go about implementing a function to check whether there is a path for a string in a matrix of characters? It moves to left, right, up and down in a matrix, and a cell for a movement.

The path can start from any entry in a matrix. If a cell is occupied by a character of a string on the path, it cannot be occupied by another character again.

How would you go about solving this problem (Psuedocode if you prefer)? My initial thinking is to interpret this as a graph problem, with a matrix location as a vertex in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: adding a slow half-java half-pseudo-code version

```
class Pair {
    public Pair(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
    public int x;
    public int y;
};

class Main {
    static Vector<Pair> singleton(Pair p) {
        Vector<Pair> v = new Vector<Pair>();
        v.insert(p);
        return v;
    }

    static void f(String str, int [][]matrix, int width, int height) {
        Vector<Vector<Pair>> v = new Vector<Vector<Pair>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
                try(i, j, str, matrix, width, height, v);
    }

    static void try(int i, int j, String str, int [][]matrix, int width, int height, Vector<Vector<Pair>> v) {
        int old_v_size = v.length;
        if (i < 0 || i >= height || j < 0 || j >= width) return;
        if (str.length == 1) v.insert(singleton(new Pair(i,j));
        try(i+1,j,str.substr(1),matrix,width,height,v);
        try(i-1,j,str.substr(1),matrix,width,height,v);
        try(i,j+1,str.substr(1),matrix,width,height,v);
        try(i,j-1,str.substr(1),matrix,width,height,v);
        for (int k = old_v_size; k < v.length; ++k) v[k].insert(new Pair(i,j));
    }

}
```

Old code follows below:

Here is a solution in Haskell (I am replacing the matrix here with a function that gets two integers and returns the value in the matrix). The function f accepts the string, the matrix function, the width, the height, and returns a list of lists of tuples for each possible solution.

```
f str matrix width height =
    concat [try i j str matrix width height | i <- [0..width-1], j <- [0..height-1] ]  


try i j (c:cs) matrix width height | i < 0 || 
                                     i >= height || 
                                     j < 0 || 
                                     j >= width || 
                                     matrix i j /= c = []
try i j [c] matrix width height = [(i,j)]
try i j (c:cs) matrix width height =
    concat  [map ((i,j):) $ try (i+1) j cs matrix width height,
             map ((i,j):) $ try (i-1) j cs matrix width height,
             map (c:) $ try i (j+1) cs matrix width height,
             map (c:) $ try i (j-1) cs matrix width height]
```

If you want it another language please specify and I will send another solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MatrixSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] find = {"M", "I", "C", "R", "O", "S", "O", "F", "T"};

        String[][] matrix = {
            {"A", "C", "P", "R", "C"},
            {"M", "S", "O", "P", "C"},
            {"I", "O", "V", "N", "I"},
            {"C", "G", "F", "M", "N"},
            {"Q", "A", "T", "I", "T"}
        };
        // printing matrix...
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j].equals(find[0])) {
                    System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
                    boolean found = recursiveMatrixFind(matrix, i, j, matrix.length, matrix.length, find, 1);                    
                    System.out.println(found);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean recursiveMatrixFind(String[][] matrix, int row, int column, int rowLength, int columnLength, String[] find, int k) {

        if (k == find.length) {
            return true;
        }

        for (int neighbourRow = row - 1; neighbourRow <= row + 1; neighbourRow++) {
            if (neighbourRow >= 0 && neighbourRow < rowLength) {
                for (int neighbourColumn = column - 1; neighbourColumn <= column + 1; neighbourColumn++) {
                    if (neighbourColumn >= 0 && neighbourColumn < columnLength) {
                        if ((!(neighbourRow == row && neighbourColumn == column))) {
                            if (matrix[neighbourRow][neighbourColumn].equals(find[k])) {
                                System.out.println(matrix[neighbourRow][neighbourColumn]);
                                boolean found = recursiveMatrixFind(matrix, neighbourRow, neighbourColumn, rowLength, columnLength, find, ++k);
                                if (found) {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```